# how to return the multiple lists from controller action to ajax success call back function

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a mvc .net project in which i have the jquery ajax request is as follows

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("getdata", "SeatPlans")",
        data: { seat_plane_id : 17},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        loadData(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed! Please try again.");
    }
});
```

which call the following controller action

```
public JsonResult getdata(int seat_plane_id)
    {
        int lid = seat_plane_id;
        List<SeatPlans> allUser = new List<SeatPlans>();
        allUser = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();
        lid++;
        List<SeatPlans> allUser1 = new List<SeatPlans>();
        allUser1 = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();

        return new JsonResult { Data = allUser,JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

the code is working fine. the controller action send the data in allUser to callback function.

but what i need is that i want to send both data in alluser and allUser1 to the success function of ajax call

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: one minute there is some problem while editing

Comment: What's with the `pre` tag with your JS?

Comment: sory sir by mistack that tag included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class that has 2 properties

```
int lid = seat_plane_id;
List<List<SeatPlans>> listOfSeatPlans (a collection of collections)

List<List<SeatPlans>> list = new ...
list.Add(allUser);
list.Add(someUsers);
```

Now you can return the class object back to JSON

Answer (score 7):

I imagine you want to keep the lists separated. Wrap them in an object.

```
var data = new { allUser = allUser , allUser1 = allUser1 }; 
return Json(yourObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You can access them in your JS like this:

```
success: function (data) {
   var allUser = data[0];
   var allUser1 = data[1];
   //use the data as you see fit.
   loadData(allUser);
   loadData(allUser1 );
},
```

Comment: even u can write the success function as- success: function (data) { loadData(data.allUser); loadData(data.allUser1);}

Answer (score 3):

You just have to modify your `Where` clause so you don't need two different lists for the users. Try this in your `getdata` method:

```
public JsonResult getdata(int seat_plane_id)
{
    int lid = seat_plane_id;
    List<SeatPlans> allUser = new List<SeatPlans>();
    allUser = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid || d.layout_id == (lid+1)).ToList();

    return new JsonResult { Data = allUser,JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

`allUser` now includes all the desired data.